# Kies won't connect to Galaxy S2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, samsung-kies

It just displays `Connecting...` forever when I plug in the phone (through USB), and nothing else happens. What should I do?

I just installed Kies, v2.3.0.12035_16

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by reinstalling the latest version of Kies and deactivating USB-Debugging BEFORE I connected my phone (Samsung Galaxy XCover) the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, plus i have try some things:

debug mode (off) then plug
debug mode (on) then plug
plug then debug mode (first off then on and vice versa)

rebooted phone and pc

installed kies, and USB drivers over the past installation

rebooted phone and pc

unistalled kies, usb drivers
rebooted phone and pc
reinstalled kies, usb drivers
rebooted phone and pc

deleted manually all the kies files, registry entry, usb drivers
rebooted phone and pc
installed kies, usb drivers
rebooted phone and pc

I have try to install kies on several computer, but all are 32 bit (win xp or at least vista)

actually, my phone has been connected to kies only one time... i remember that time it was some of the first try, about a year and half ago... then, nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Before ur usb connect with the computer,
go.Setting-->Application-->development-->USB debugging(no tick) 
open Kies connect USB maybe it is work....
if still not , reopen the phone..connect again...
i hope that it can help u.....also understand my poor eng....